# Maven SCM plugin

Tags: maven, version-control, maven-plugin

Can someone explain in plain words what are the main use cases of the Maven `SCM` plugin?

More specifically: when is it required during the build lifecycle? how it relates to GIT/SVN and to the `mvn release` plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Plain copy from the [plugin pages](http://maven.apache.org/scm/):

In addition, Maven SCM provides 2 tools to directly use it:

- maven-scm-plugin: a Maven plugin, where each SCM command is implemented as a plugin goal,
- maven-scm-client: a simple SCM command line tool.

Sometimes it's useful to implement task without using specific vcs commands...ci servers sometimes used...

Typically it's not required during the build life cycle..

The whole api and implementations of maven-scm are used in maven-release-plugin to support a wide area of version control systems not only svn/git...there are more in the wild...